# Textview with link mail highlighting in TableViewCell changes tintColor for seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview

I have a textView in my tableViewCell. In the Interfacebuilder I set a link, mail and address detection for the textview. So all the links, mail and addresses are highlighted. The textview is selectable, too.

I'm working with an autorefresh, so the content of the the tableViewCell will reload all 30 seconds. Everytime when this is happen, the highlighting disappears for < 1 second and the the highlighting comes back.

Sometimes this happens to at the initialize load of the tableViewCell.

There seems to be a bunch of bugs in iOS 7... but I use minimum 8.4.

So does anybody know this bug oder has some help? Thank you

Comment: why you have to use autorefresh?

Comment: it's the concept of the application... Alternative there would be a manually refresh. With the manually refresh the problem is the same

Comment: but you put this as code or in storyboard?

Comment: the link detection is only in storyboard in the textview element. The autorefresh/manual refresh is programmatically with tableview.beginRefreshing()

Comment: try this "yourLabel.highlighted = true" inside your code

Comment: I use a textView, it seems that there is no highlighted attribute

Comment: Yes, I thought that the text in the textField became a label. Try something about ".addAttribute"

Comment: I changed:  
subtitleTextView.text  = stringWithLinks
to
subtitleTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: stringWithLinks)
but no difference

Comment: probably because you don't have added an attribute. "  let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor() ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: stringWithLinks, attributes: myAttribute) "

Comment: Ahh this is your intention. Yeah this is a possibility that I will do. The thing is that I parse then two times. My own parser that highlighted all links. And the detection parser in the textview. I hoped that I can prevent this...

Comment: I think that this is right. I write this solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the attribute method to customize your string in a method similar to this:

```
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor() ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: stringWithLinks, attributes: myAttribute)
```

So you have your customized string. 
Good job

Answer (score 0):

@Carlo 
This example doesn't work for me.

**Important**: In the Interfacebuilder the textview has to be selectable = true/on

What worked for me is my own parser to get all links/mails (whatever you want):

```
 func searchForLinksAndMailsInString(remark: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {


    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: remark)

    //set default color for non links and mails 
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:remark.characters.count))

    //search for valid websites
    let matchesForWebsite = Model.sharedInstance().parseForRegexInText(RegexFilter.regexFindAllValidWebsites, text: remark)

    //make links clickable
    for match in matchesForWebsite {
        attributedString.setAsLink(match, linkURL: match)
    }

    //same as websites just for mails
    let matchesForMails = Model.sharedInstance().parseForRegexInText(RegexFilter.regexFindAllValidMails, text: remark)

    for match in matchesForMails {
        attributedString.setAsLMail(match, mail: match)
    }


    return attributedString

}
```

Extension to make the results clickable

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
//not my work see [here][1]
public func setAsLink(textToFind:String, linkURL:String) -> Bool {

    let foundRange = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(textToFind)
    if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        if let linkURLToURL = NSURL(string: linkURL) {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURLToURL, range: foundRange)
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}


public func setAsLMail(textToFind:String, mail:String) -> Bool {

    let foundRange = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(textToFind)
    if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        if let mailToURL = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(mail)") {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: mailToURL, range: foundRange)
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
 }
}
```

How to call:

`let attributedString = searchForLinksAndMailsInString(remark)
 subtitleTextView.attributedText = attributedString`

My regexs (they work, no guarantee for elegance):

```
class RegexFilter {
    static let regexFindAllValidMails = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    static let regexFindAllValidWebsites = "(((http(s)?://)(www.)?)|(www.))([a-z][a-z0-9]*).([a-z]{2,3})"
}
```